# Adding a modifier to an auto-generated variable getter

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to add a modifier to the auto-generated getter for a given variable?  My use case is I am marking a contract as being in-process for updating and setting a modifier flag; I'd like to prevent reading the contract state while it's updating, restricted by this modifier.

I understand I could create my own getter, but then I am returning a tuple with no keys.  When I access one of the structs via the auto-generated getter via web3 for a mapping at a specific mapping key (of the form `mapping(uint => SomeStruct)`, I get the `SomeStruct` instance along with the struct keys, which is nice but unexpected, since I'm not using the ABIEncoderV2 experimental encoder.  I'd like to keep the ability to return this object, which as I've stated I don't think is possible if I define  my own getter, without the experimental encoder.

Comment: Why don't you simply declare the variable `private` (or `internal`), and then implement a getter function explicitly?

Comment: @goodvibration I explained this in the question.  Currently unless you are using the experimental encoder, you cannot return a struct from a function.  However, when I access the struct via the mapping, by mapping key, I get back an object with the struct keys, which as I mentioned is unexpected.  If I were to implement my own getting, I can only return a tuple of the dereferenced values, there are no keys returned.

Comment: You can return a tuple, is that not good enough for your needs?

Comment: For example, `function func() external view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256)`

Comment: You can pass to this function the `uint` which you use in order to query the `mapping`, and inside the function return your structure as a tuple (list) of values.

Comment: @goodvibration Sorry but it seems you are reading neither the original question nor my answers to your suggestion.  Again - when you use the built in mapping getter to return an item at an index, you get an *object* with keys.  That's a very nice feature, especially since I am writing a contract where *I am not the only consumer*.  It's nicer to have an object returned with named keys versus a flat list, no?  I am not the only consumer of this app.  So I don't want to return a flat tuple of many items, when the built-in getter gives me something more robust.  Hopefully it is clear now.